# If $(X,T)$ is a countable $T_1$-space with no isolated points, then $(X,T)$ is not a Baire space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $(X,T)$ is a countable $T_1$-space with no isolated points, then $(X,T)$ is not a Baire space.

Since $(X,T)$ is a $T_1$-space, all finite sets are closed $\Rightarrow $ open sets are of the form $X$ \ $F$ where F is finite. Any open dense subsets of X must be of the form $X$ \ $F_n$.  So if $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}X$ \ $F_n $ = $X$ \ $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n \Rightarrow $ $X$ \ $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n \neq X. $  From here I can't figure out how to use the fact that there are no isolated points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not true that all open sets are of the form $X\setminus F$, where $F$ is finite; what *is* true is that every set of that form is open.

HINT: For each $x\in X$ let $U_x=X\setminus\{x\}$. Because $X$ is $T_1$, you know that each $U_x$ is open. Use the fact that $X$ has no isolated points to show that each $U_x$ is also dense. Then consider $\bigcap_{x\in X}U_x$.

Comment: So:  Because $X$ \ $ \{x_n \}$ is a subset, and it's intersection with any other open set (excluding the null set) is nonempty, $X$ \ $ \{x_n \}$ is dense.  Therefore $X$ \ $ \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{x_n \} = \emptyset $.  And the closure of the null set is the null set which implies it is not a Baire space.

Does that make sense?

Comment: @Oliver: Yes, though you might want to explain exactly why $U_x\cap V$ is non-empty for each non-empty open $V\subseteq X$: the only non-empty subset of $X$ disjoint from $U_x$ is $\{x\}$, and since $X$ has no isolated points, $\{x\}$ isn’t open.